# Using mysql like clause in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Mysql query that works fine for me is :

```
SELECT *
FROM `review_details`
WHERE category = 'italian'
AND review LIKE '%cozy%';
```

It display results.

```
SELECT *  FROM `review_details`    WHERE category = 'italian'    AND review LIKE %cozy%';
```

But when I execute in my php script :

```
$word = 'cozy';
$select = mysqli($con,"SELECT *  FROM `review_details`    WHERE category = 'italian'    AND review LIKE %.$word.%' ");
```

Then it does not display any result.

Please see query is correct, when I change the condition it gives result.

Comment: Your first two queries are different. Make them *both* work and you have solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285701/using-mysql-like-clause-in-php

Comment: You have wrong sql sentence, and also you need to use `mysqli_query` not `mysqli`. See my answer

Comment: syntax mistake my friend

Comment: I can't believe this question was twice upvoted

Answer (score 3):

Change `LIKE %.$word.%'` into `LIKE '%$word%'`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as..

```
$select = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `review_details` WHERE category = 'italian' AND review LIKE '%$word%' ");
```

The concatenation is not at all neccessary.

It should be `mysqli_query`. Pointed out by [Husseyin.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796105/huseyin-babal)

Comment: It's not a problem as long as one have an admiring friend who prefers one's answer over all others

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Admiring friend O.o ?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, you need to use [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) or `$mysqli->query` (PDO) , and some quote problem in sql sentence. You can use following;

```
$word = 'cozy';
$select = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *  FROM `review_details`    
                WHERE `category` = 'italian'    AND `review` LIKE '%$word%' ");
```

Or if you are using pdo, you can use;

```
// $mysqli is the conn object
$word = 'cozy';
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT *  FROM `review_details`    
                WHERE `category` = 'italian'    AND `review` LIKE '%$word%' ");
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense The question is very suspicious, sql sentence is wrong also function is wrong. I couldn't understand which library OP using or not. I have stated both of them. Do you think shall I remove PDO section?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$word = 'cozy';
$select = mysqli($con,"SELECT *  FROM `review_details`    
                WHERE `category` = 'italian'    AND `review` LIKE '%$word%' ");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$word = 'cozy';
$select = mysqli($con,"SELECT *  FROM `review_details`    WHERE category = 'italian'    AND review LIKE '%{$word}%' ");
```

But i suggest to use mysqli object oriented style instead of procedural style. Then use $con->prepare().